# Unable to store bcrypt hashed password from JSON into mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, bcrypt

I'm unable to store bcrypt hashed password from JSON into mongodb using mongoose. I think there is a mistake in my implementation of setPassword schema method. I've replaced 'bcrypt' with 'crypto' implementation and it worked fine. The hashed string was stored in database. But unable to do so with 'bcrypt'

My model.js implementation

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// User Schema
const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    index: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String
  },
  email: {
    type: String
  },
  name: {
    type: String
  }
});

userSchema.methods.setPassword =  function(password) {
  const saltRounds = 10;
  bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
    this.password = hash;
  });
};

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

My router controller implementation

```
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('User');

const register = (req, res) => {

  const newUser = new User();

  newUser.name = req.body.name;
  newUser.email = req.body.email;
  newUser.username = req.body.username;
  newUser.setPassword(req.body.password);

  newUser.save((err) => {
    // Validations error
    if (err) {
      res.status(400).json(err);
      return;
    }

    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: 'Registration Successful'
    });

  });
};
```

Comment: There could be an error generated by `bcrypt.hash` that you're not verifying.

Comment: @BrahmaDev I've added the line if (err) throw err; but it still doesn't throw any error.

Comment: Can you try the synchronous version. `this.password=bcrypt.hashSync(password, saltRounds);`

Comment: Thank you. bcrypt.hashSync(password, saltRoutnds); worked. Seems this.password is not pointing to newUser inside bcrypt.hash(). Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` points to `bcrypt.hash` not the userSchema object.

```
userSchema.methods.setPassword =  function(password) {
  const saltRounds = 10;
  var that = this;
  bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
    that.password = hash;
  });
};
```

UPDATE: Use callback or promises

```
userSchema.methods.setPassword =  function(password, cb) {
  const saltRounds = 10;
  var that = this;
  bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
    that.password = hash;
    cb();
  });
};

newUser.setPassword(req.body.password, function(){
    //Rest of code
});
```

Comment: This is not working. Printing 'that.password' inside bcrypt is giving hash but printing undefined outside the bcrypt.

Comment: @JajatiKeshariR If `that.password` remains undefined then that would mean `bcrypt.hash` is truly asynchronous and you'd need to wait for callback.